# Callabe statement Oracle Update Skip locked fetching out of sequence error

Tags: java, oracle, function, cursor, callable-statement

Following is the Function which I am calling using Callabe Statement.Statement fetches a cursor since rowtype is not possible in java.But am getting an error of out of sequence.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

```
    create or replace FUNCTION DEQUEUE
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  c_Result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN  c_Result FOR SELECT * FROM QUEUE_SKIP_LOCKED WHERE ROWNUM=1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
declare
  c_fdbQueuerow sys_refcursor;
  l_queueRow QUEUE_SKIP_LOCKED%rowtype;
  begin
  c_fdbQueuerow := c_Result;
loop
    fetch c_fdbQueuerow into l_queueRow;
     IF l_queueRow.key IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE QUEUE_SKIP_LOCKED SET STATUS='WORKING' WHERE KEY=l_queueRow.key;
    END IF;
    exit when c_fdbQueuerow%notfound;
  end loop;
    RETURN c_fdbQueuerow;
end;
  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  RAISE;
END dequeue;
```

Callabe Statement is as follows

```
session.connection().setAutoCommit(false);
    cs = session.connection().prepareCall("{?=call dequeue}");
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cs.executeUpdate();
    session.connection().commit();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
    while(rs.next())
```

Comment: I have some problems trying to understand that function. What do you want that function to do?

Comment: The function return a single row and need to update one column of the row to 'Working' and return the same row back.(Rowtype is not returned in callable so the cursor is returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the cursor returns one row and that row has already been fetched.

Do not issue a fetch statement after the last row has been retrieved - there are no more rows to fetch.

Better split the function into:

1 A function that returns the ID of the row that has to be updated.

2 A procedure that does the update

3 Further processing using the ID.

Comment: This would work but would create an additional overhead to use the ID returned to fetch the recordand perform some action on the java side, for the same reason is why I wanted rowtype any possible modifications where this can be acheieved.